# Should creating an AWS Hosted Zone update the name servers for a registered domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I've registered a domain using AWS Route 43 e.g. `abc.example`.

I then used Terraform to create a hosted zone specifying the domain name `abc.example`.

I then noticed that the name servers specified in the Hosted Zones screen of the console and the Registered Domains screen where different.

I've resolved this by manually changing the domain name (also using the Route 53 console) to use the same name servers as those specified in the hosted zone.

However, should this happen automatically when I create a hosted zone? My thinking was that the creation of the hosted zone would tie together both the domain name and in my case my Cloudfront hosted site content but this does not *appear* to be the case.

Hope someone can clarify.

Answer (score 2):

This also caught me out when I first started using AWS with Route 53. The reason for this is that when you register a domain AWS will automatically set up a Hosted Zone for you and this gives the impression the two are linked.

This provides more information...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2xLV7pCOLI&t=391s

[Slide from AWS re:Invent regarding R53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZshFT.png)

However, in theory the registrar could be anyone so there is a process known as *delegation* where by you inform the registration which name servers to use for your domain.

So to answer your question: no the process is not automatic when you create a zone, you just get this impression if your domain registrar is AWS as they will create the hosted zone for you.

You can use Terraform to create the zone, but then you need to go into the domain name settings in R53 and update the domain name with the nameservers from the hosted zone.

Comment: oh my gosh!! After hours of painful search I got with this. I had been banging my head against the wall for a few days now. Thanks kind sir.